How to count number of repeated values in a column
I have a column with letters that can occurs more than one time like this:

I want to count how many times the repeating occurs. For example [A,B,C,A,D,F,A,B] = 3 (2 times A, one time B).
The problem is I don't know how many rows there will be. I'm importing this table from a web API.
I need one formula that automatically counts it whenever I refresh the data. I tried with countif but I don't know how to implement dynamic rows.

The formula is
=MAX(SCAN(1,DROP(UNIQUE(A:A),1),LAMBDA(aa,b,COUNTIF(A:A,b)+aa-1)))-1
Do not place it in column A, since it is the dynamic range of the data. (circular reference)


Judging by your minimalistic question I think you could try:

Formula in C2:
=GROUPBY(A.:.A,A.:.A,ROWS,1,0)

Swap A.:.A for TOCOL(A:A,1) if you don't yet have access to dynamic ranges.

I dont know how can i expand my question i w think i writed as simplest as i can. I tried with groupby and tocol but all i got is the error "There's a proble with this formula". Anyway thank for help.

Works perfectly if you have a recent version of Excel. I guess you could add something like =SUM(CHOOSECOLS(GROUPBY(A.:.A,A.:.A,ROWS,1,0),2)-1) to get the total that OP is after.

A slight variation on previous answer to deal with the case where there may be blanks in the range:
=REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1)),LAMBDA(b,c,b+COUNTIF(A:A,c)-1))



This solution uses the formula of the questioner Statto of this discussion:
Restarting and resuming a running total for multiple values
One formula for scenarios with and without blanks:
=SUM(N(MAP(A2:A11,LAMBDA(a,COUNTIFS(INDEX(A2:A11,1):a,a)))>1)) 

=SUM(N(MAP(B2:B14,LAMBDA(a,COUNTIFS(INDEX(B2:B14,1):a,a)))>1))



